# FFMPEG - Creating script to convert a video into audio file (or anything related really) + diverses questions

Tags: video, ffmpeg, audio, conversion, script

Good day everyone. Im making my babysteps into ffmpeg, and so far this tool has been really helpfull. Anyway.
Im currently using this line as a convertion basis :

```
ffmpeg -i name.mov -c:v libx264 name.wav
```

But while searching through the question here i've seen that :

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vn -ar 44100 -ac 1 -b:a 32k -f mp3 audio.mp3
```

Or even this (a script) :

```
%%f in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -i "%%f" -vn -ar 44100 -ac 1 -b:a 32k -f mp3 "%%~nf.mp3"
```

So now let's dive into it. Im wondering *if* i can merge the two first ones like that :

```
ffmpeg -i name.mov -vn -ar 48000 -ac 2 -b:a 32k libx264 -f wav name.wav
```

And how i can modify it by making it scripted. 
Also im wondering if the ffmpeg i got is good because i don't have a command prompt that directly open cmd into `cd bin`. As im forced to write everytime the entire path.

Thanks in advance. S'Aarum.

Comment: *"As im forced to write everytime the entire path."* Add ffmpeg.exe to the environment variables. [See here](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/20495/how-do-i-set-up-and-use-ffmpeg-in-windows/20496#20496)

Comment: Looks like you've already seen that page. One of your commands is the example command there.

Answer (score 0):

`-vn` + `-c:v libx264` Does not make any sense. 
This is saying "Don't encode video, but use libx264 to encode no video."

You also can not set a bitrate for wav because it's a noncompressed format.

So your command becomes:

`ffmpeg -i name.mov -vn -ar 48000 -ac 2 name.wav`

Comment: `-vn` can be omitted for wav output, but it makes no difference.